# undefined reference to cv::plot::Plot2d::render bur for cv::plot::Plot2d::create everything was ok

Tags: c++, opencv, compiler-errors, g++

I use OpenCV 4.5.1 and I want to create a plot, but I've recive an error:

> undefined reference to `cv::plot::Plot2d::render`

with code like that:

```cpp
Mat plot_img(2, 100, CV_8U);
Ptr<plot::Plot2d> plotCOLs;
plotCOLs = plot::Plot2d::create(colX, colY);
plotCOLs -> cv::plot::Plot2d::render(plot_img);
imshow("KM controller", plot_img);
```

Is the problem because of the render function? With `create`, everything is ok.

Comment: [`virtual void render (OutputArray _plotResult)=0`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d0/d1e/classcv_1_1plot_1_1Plot2d.html) means it (probably) doesn't have implementation

Comment: Presumably implemented in some derived class that's constructed by the call to `create`. Just do `plotCOLs->render(plot_img);`.

Comment: and ofcource `plotCOLs = ...` is not the same as `plotCOLs -> ...`

Comment: @DanMašek you're right.

But earlier i try this, but it didn't work, so I tried to use tip from other forum.

At the end, I've must recompile library, and everything is fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dan Mašek, was right. I follow wrong suggestion from net.

```
Mat plot_img(2, 100, CV_8U);
Ptr<plot::Plot2d> plotCOLs;
plotCOLs = plot::Plot2d::create(colX, colY);
plotCOLs -> render(plot_img);
imshow("KM controller", plot_img);
```

But the answer have second part, I've had to recompile library, becouse there was an error in this file. That's the reason why I's looking for answer in net